# redirect_to inside view - RAILS - DEVISE redirect to user_session_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, path, devise

How do I redirect_to a certain path or page inside the view. I've read that redirect_to is an ActionController something, and cannot be used in the view. How can I do this in the view using only Rails, and how can I in addition to this write the redirection inside the controller or the model or helper and then just writing in the instance variable inside the view. I am using Devise. I do not want to use Javascript nor JQuery. Just Rails!

I tried this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  @Uchecker = user_signed_in?
  redirect_to user_session-path
end
```

Comment: Your redirect should be in your controller. If you want something in your view - add a link for the user to select. You can add the Uchecker in a method as a before_filter

Comment: I'll try doing like so then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the *redirect_to* from a controller, instead of rendering a view, what it does is to render an http redirect

Now if you want to do a redirection from the view, you can still use javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = "<%= user_session_path %>";
</script>
```

Not the best practice but it works, and its a common practice for intermediate pages (i.e. when you search for a trip, the trip search could take like 60 seconds, so you render a view where you show something to the user like you are searching for the best trip, and you do a javascript redirection, once the result is ready, the page is loaded).